# Drupal - clean database

Tags: drupal

Is there a way to clear or clean the database of all the unnessecary entries that was added by amodules that have since been uninstalled. Ive created my site but have added alot of modules to ploay around with, I have no removed all of those I dont use, but just wondering if there is a way top clear the database etc.. to ensure nothing unused was left behind ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your own content that you would want to keep AND you have used the uninstall feature for all the modules that you have installed, then the only route is to manually check. if you don't have much content you could export it and replace the db with a clean one, then put your content back into it.

Comment: To clarify: Every well-written module has it's own uninstallation processes that are run when you formally uninstall (not just disable) the module. Those routines are the only thing in the system that would recognize all the changes a given module might make to your database.

Comment: Yeah, any module that leaves behind data after uninstall is broken, and you should file an issue in that module's queue on drupal.org.

Comment: thanks guys, much appreciated. i've uninstalled most modules now and I have my speed back. I also found the following module - http://drupal.org/project/schema  - one of the features are "Schema comparison: the module compares the live database structure with the schema structure declared by all enabled modules, reporting on any missing or incorrect tables"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Schema](http://drupal.org/project/schema) module for discovering the remaining tables from not properly uninstalled modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use DEVEL modules reinstall feature if you only want to clean the database but don't want remove the module.